# Why would an omnipotent, omnibenevolent create a universe with no humanity for billions of years?

Tags: existence-of-god, creationism

The interpretation that god is omnibenevolent and omnipotent suggests that the universe was created with the eventual goal of humanity to come into existence. If this were the case, what was the purpose of the early universe when it lacked humans? Certainly it would have been easier for an omnipotent god to introduce humans from the outset with conditions fit for human life as they are now? And if not then what was the early period of the universe serve?

Assumptions: the Big Bang occurred and was done by the first-mover.

Many thanks!

Comment: It is not just the age of the Universe but its size also- rather like buying trillions of cat baskets thirteen billion years before you buy a single cat to put in one of them.

Comment: What's the necessary connection you perceive between a Good and Powerful God and the eventual goal of creating humanity? And for that matter, what's a trillion year wait to an immortal? I'm not sure you've outlined your dilemma clearly enough here to have it be answerable.

Comment: A trillion extra years to a creator who is ambivalent to time and creation is perfectly reasonable. But if that creator had the characteristic of being omnibenevolent towards humanity, and it created the universe for them, then I’d assume that everything that they did had the purpose of progressing this goal, no? And for an omnipotent creator this can all be done instantly, so what would be the purpose of a trillion years of faff when the creator’s goal is humanity?

Comment: But a trillion years is an instant in the context of eternity.  It just seems like a long time to us.

Comment: But why would a creator do nothing for a a trillion years? Does that not imply that the creator had no purpose?

Comment: Why would an omnipotent, omnibenevolent deity spoil his perfect universe by letting humans into it?

Comment: P.S.  It is considered disrespectful to some people to not capitalize the word God.

Comment: @MarcoOcram or like storing your data on a cloud server a hundred billion times farther away than local storage? When distance doesn't mean appreciable delay, it doesn't mean mean much at all.

Comment: Perhaps the truth is that God's aim in creating the Universe was to enable the evolution of a perfect civilisation of uniformly God-fearing individuals, and that civilisation formed billions of years ago on the other side of the Universe. Maybe we are an unintended side effect.

Comment: God's will is unscrutable.

Comment: This question goes to the personal motivation of an individual (albeit omnipotent, omniscient etc..). It can't reasonably be answered with anything but speculation unless that individual makes an explicit public statement (preferably in person, not through a spokesperson/spokesangel).

Comment: @Hooman Haven't you ever started a project but then put it off for 10 or 20 years before you picked it up again? Or let something sit in the oven for half an hour before you could do the next step? Also presumptuous to assume humans were the objective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael Hall's answer is good for addressing the question as posed, but I think the question as posed rests on a weak premise to begin with if it's supposed to relate to real-life religions.

The premise that the universe was created for humans is bad theology in any of Judaism, Christianity, or Islam. God did not create the universe for humans, God created the universe and the humans in it for God.

We could start with Genesis (observing that the most straightforward interpretation for why God created was because *it was good*), but for something explicit and literal, we can start with the Tanakh:

> But now, this is what the Lord says— he who created you, [descendants
> of] Jacob, he who formed you, Israel [...] everyone who is called by
> my name, **whom I created for my glory**, whom I formed and made... (Isaiah 43)

An examination of the early Christian scriptures shows the idea is firmly entrenched by the 1st century:

> For from him and through him and **to him are all things. To him be
> glory for ever.** (Romans 11)

> In bringing many sons and daughters to glory, it was fitting that God,
> **for whom and through whom everything exists**, should make the pioneer
> of their salvation perfect through what he suffered. (Hebrews 2)

Early Christians attributed the same properties to Jesus:

> He [Jesus] is the image of the invisible God, the first-born of all creation;
> for in him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible
> and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or
> authorities—all things were created through him **and for him. He is
> before all things, and in him all things hold together.** (Colossians 1)

The Quran of course jettisoned the idea of Jesus being the eternal co-original image of the invisible God, but doubles down on humans being created for God:

> And I [God] did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me. (Quran 51:56)

In fact, they aren't even the most important part of the creation:

> The creation of the heavens and earth is greater than the creation of
> mankind, but most of the people do not know. (Quran 40:57)

Answer (score 1):

But who said they did nothing?

Realize that our scale and concept of time is completely meaningless to such a being.

The question is like a transient quark, flickering into and out of existence, and in that brief flash pondering why you took the time to yawn this morning when you woke up, or why you stirred your coffee for 3 seconds before sipping it. You weren't doing nothing, you were preparing for your day.

Perhaps a great many things were being accomplished during this time to prepare for the eventual arrival of humans.  Or perhaps it wasn't as long as we think it was.  Processes we can measure at a certain rate now may have happened much more rapidly in the past.

In any case, the exact reasons for whatever happened or didn't happen during the time before humans cannot be known.

Comment: Yeah, the cats knocked over my coffee this morning, so I had to create some more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not seem conclusive to me. Do you suppose that creating human beings is an act of **benevolence**? Being benevolent to whom?

Before their creation humans did not exist. One cannot compare “non-existent” humans before the creation with existent humans after the creation.

As a consequence, the cause to ponder - under the aspect of benevolence - about the billions of years, where the universe existed without humans, fell away.

Please correct me if I missunderstand your question.

Answer (score -1):

At least 3 viable fetuses:

1. The world was created, as the *biblia sacra* says, 10,000 years ago.
2. The *biblia sacra* is ... obviously ... a pack of lies.
3. This is the most intriguing of the possibilities ... 10,000 *biblical "years"* is 14 billion *solar* years OR, if you're a down-to-earth person, 10,000 *biblical "years" is 4 billion *solar* years.